# Link in IE8 is not clickable

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, hyperlink

I have the following structure:

```
<div><a href="/users" alt="Login" title="Login"><input type="submit" class="buttonvmSe" value="Add To Favorites" name="addtofavorites" title="Add To Favorites"></a></div>
```

The problem is that the  link is not working on IE8, but on the others browsers is working fine. What could be the problem?

Works with this:

```
 <input onclick="location.href=\'/'.$finalUrl.'\'" type="submit" class="buttonvmSe" />
```

Comment: Why would you put an `<input type="submit" />` inside of an `<a>` tag? Try changing it into a button. `<button>Add To Favorites</button>`

Comment: I'm not quite sure there's an ´alt´ attribute defined for ´a´ tag...

Comment: @Bartdude There isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect its because you are wrapping a submit button in an A tag. Try this:

```
<div><input type="button" onclick="location.href='/users'" class="buttonvmSe" value="Add To Favorites" name="addtofavorites" title="Add To Favorites"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think having

`<input type="submit" class="buttonvmSe" value="Add To Favorites" name="addtofavorites" title="Add To Favorites">`

in an `<a>` tag is valid, try changing it to this:

```
<div>
    <a href="/users" title="Login">
        <button class="buttonvmSe" title="Add To Favorites">Add To Favorites</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

As for the alt attribute, `alt` is **not** a valid attribute for an `<a>` tag.
Please refer to the [HTML attribute reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)